# Uploading and downloading files to/from Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I see that the Firebase has already a new beta version released, called Cloud Firestore. In the documentation all operations with the documents are described very well, but I am not able to find anything about uploading and downloading media files into the Cloud Firestore using Android...

Does anyone has any information/tutorial etc for uploading/downloading media files (for example mp3 files and images)?

Thank you very much in advance for the answers!

Comment: you can't upload files to cloud firestore it is non sql database. For storage use Firebase Storage.

Comment: you mean firebase storage on uploading and downloading.

Comment: Do you mean that there is an option to use both - cloud firestore for the documents (the data) instead of the firebase realtime database and the firebase storage for the files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't store files to Firebase Cloud Firestore instead you can use the combination of Firebase Storage and Firebase Cloud Firestore to active the desired functionality.

**Firebase Storage** is to storage files and download from it.

**Firebase Realtime Database** is to store json no-sql database on it.

**Firebase Cloud Firestore** is advanced version of Firebase realtime database the difference from Realtime database is that it is Document based non-sql database.

Suppose you need to develop an application with database and storage you need combination of any of Database with Firebase Storage. Store files in firebase storage and save their urls in firebase realtime or firebase cloud firestore for downloading and uploading them.

To Upload file on firebase storage :

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;

//for firebase storage
firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageReference;
storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("url");

final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("" + imageName);

imageFolder.putFile(saveUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask . TaskSnapshot >() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        //submitted sucessfully
        imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Uri >() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                Log.wtf(TAG, "download image path : " + uri.toString());
                //now you have path to the uploaded file save this path to your database
                uploadDataToUserUploadedImage(uri);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener () {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                getMvpView().stopProgressLoading();
                getMvpView().onError("Fail to submit feedback " + e.getMessage());
                getMvpView().hideLoading();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener < UploadTask . TaskSnapshot >() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress =(100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
        getMvpView().publishProgress((int) progress);
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: " + progress);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener () {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        getMvpView().hideLoading();
        getMvpView().stopProgressLoading();
        getMvpView().onError("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Do you have link to any tutorial for doing this?

Comment: for learning about firestore you can follow this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#0

Comment: my pleasure you can ping me for further help. thanks