# Using example code to upload files to Firestore returns a 404 with Code=-13010 "Object images/rivers.jpg does not exist."

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

#### Description

When trying to upload a file to Firestore the server returns a 404 with file not found.
The code used to upload a file from memory is the code listed on the official documentation [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) under `Upload from data in memory`:

```
// Data in memory
let data = Data()

// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
  guard let metadata = metadata else {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    return
  }
  // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
  let size = metadata.size
  // You can also access to download URL after upload.
  riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      return
    }
  }
}
```

The rules settings for the bucket are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 5, 24);
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas what problem is causing the issue?

#### Reproducing the issue

Use the sample code described above to upload data from memory to a Firestore bucket with the rules described above.

#### Firebase SDK Version

10.7.0

#### Xcode Version

14.3

#### Installation Method

CocoaPods

#### Firebase Product(s)

Firestore

#### Targeted Platforms

iOS

#### Relevant Log Output

```bash
▿ Optional<Error>
  - some : Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object images/rivers.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x282a27b10 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=404 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 65, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, ResponseErrorCode=404, ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, object=images/rivers.jpg, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found."
  }
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Object images/rivers.jpg does not exist., data={length = 65, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, bucket=nfluxtv.appspot.com}
```

Link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11157

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code example is for Google Cloud Storage for Firebase.

You cannot upload files to Firestore itself which I didn't know: [Uploading and downloading files to/from Google Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529957/uploading-and-downloading-files-to-from-google-cloud-firestore)